# Select Second Greatest Using GREATEST() Method

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to select the greatest and second greatest numbers from multiple columns?

Example:

```
Col1 = 0;
Col2 = 4;
Col3 = 6;
Col4 = 3;
```

My greatest would be 6 followed by a second greatest of 4.

I'm trying implement something like this:

```
SELECT GREATEST(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) AS High, 
       GREATEST(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4) AS Low 
       WHERE Low < High FROM tbl;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 4 columns you can do it like this:

```
select
  greatest(col1, col2, col3, col4) high,
  greatest(col1, col2, col3) + 
  greatest(col1, col2, col4) + 
  greatest(col1, col3, col4) + 
  greatest(col2, col3, col4) -  
  3 * greatest(col1, col2, col3, col4) low
from tablename
```

You add all the greatest of all the combinations of 3 columns and subtract the greatest of all multiplied by 3 because out of the 4 combinations the 3 will result to the greatest of all.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cmLkKRtLp9QLm8tfVmKkh/0).
Results:

```
| high | low |
| ---- | --- |
| 6    | 4   |
```

Comment: A very verbose query, but gets the job done. Thank you. Was originally determining it through C++ logic after capturing all columns but wanted to put it all in a query to simplify it. Not sure which solution is simpler now though, hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Forpas solution is clever, but it doesn't work with non-numeric data.  A more conventional solution works when the values are different and not null:

```
select greatest(a, b, c, d),
       (case greatest(a, b, c, d)
            when a then greatest(b, c, d)
            when b then greatest(a, c, d)
            when c then greatest(a, b, d)
            else d
        end)
from t;
```

Comment: @forpas . . . I'm not sure what I was thinking.  I changed the answer.